# All "pixels" touched by line segment

Tags: analytic-geometry

Say you have a line segment somewhere on the Cartesian plane that connects the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, and there are "pixels". For simplicity's sake, let's say that the pixels are 1 unit by 1 unit.

[image: It took forever to make this picture in paint.]

How could I go about finding all the pixels that the line touches?
(This is part of a computer program, so I would prefer something fast)

Thanks!

Comment: I found an answer on google. Should I delete the question?

Comment: You can answer it yourself here, and either accept your own answer or wait to see if someone posts a better one.

Comment: I think Bresenham's line algorithm is what you are looking for.

Comment: This site may be useful: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/LineThroughGrid.shtml#solution